# Why does this link not work on iPhone?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, iphone, ssl

Go to [this site here](https://recrutz.com/), and click on 'Subscribe' in the navigation at the top.

Then click on the 'Subscribe Now' button.

It should redirect you to the registration page.

On an iPhone in both Safari and Chrome it doesn't.

It basically just redirects back to the same page.

It is just a normal `href` link, with no JS or anything like that.

This link works if you try it from a desktop machine or a laptop or some other device.

Other links also work on the iPhone on that same page.

I am not quite sure how to debug weird front-end behaviors on an iPhone.

**Edit 1**

It seems that it doesn't work on Safari on OS X. It works on Chrome on OS X though.

Not sure how to debug on Safari though.

**Edit 2**

Ok I figured out how to access developer tools within Safari and I was able to track it down to this:

[image]

So what jumped out at me is that perhaps I didn't `force_ssl = true` within my production environment.

But when I did that, I ended up getting stuck in a redirect loop and the whole site crashed:

```
The domain_name.com page isn’t working
domain_name.com redirected you too many times.
Try clearing your cookies.
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
```

**Edit 3**

This is a simple `link_to` tag like so:

```
        <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
            <%= link_to "Subscribe Now", new_subscription_path(plan: "basic-annual"), class: "btn btn-success btn-lg subscribe-btn" %>
        </div>
```

That generates the following HTML:

```
<div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                <a class="btn btn-success btn-lg subscribe-btn" href="/subscription/new?plan=basic-annual">Subscribe Now</a>
            </div>
```

There is no JS related to it. But I do think this has something to do with SSL.

Comment: I noticed there is a javascript error in the page. It could prevent Turbolinks from working as expected. Can you fix it, to isolate things? `$("input.cc-num").payment is not a function`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like Turbolinks is acting up. You can disable it for a specific link with `data-turbolinks="false"`:

```
<a class="btn btn-success btn-lg subscribe-btn" data-turbolinks="false" href="/subscription/new?plan=basic-annual">Subscribe Now</a>
```

Makes your link work perfectly fine. :D

Comment: I am still getting the issue, even after I tried this :(

Comment: Actually I tried the old way to disable TL and that didn't work....but this did. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I noticed you're using Turbolinks (vanilla Rails install?).

For some reason, Turbolinks is requesting the http version of your site. That's why nothing happens on Safari, it's just blocking the content because the page is served via https, so ajax should be https too:

> The page at https://recrutz.com/subscription/new?plan=basic-annual was not allowed to display insecure content from http://recrutz.com/register.

Can you try updating Turbolinks? This already fixed issue looks relevant to your problem: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks-classic/issues/570

Comment: Rails 5.0.1 -- not particularly vanilla. It comes with Turbolinks 5.0.1. You are right though, that does seem to be the issue. But updating TL isn't the fix...because I am using the latest version of TL that came with Rails 5.